# file-folder association or belonging

Tags: c#, c++, file, associations, directory

When I save a webpage in firefox, i choose to save it entirely. Saved html file becomes associated with a folder that contains images etc..

When i went to rename the HTML file, it tells me that to doing so would
mean the file would no longer "belong" to the folder containing the
graphics.

If i delete the folder containing the graphics, the HTML file also get
deleted. (it's the same with changing directories of html file)

There are 2 ways to destroy this "belonging to" that I discovered.
 1. rename the HTML file and agree to lose the association when a dialogue box popped up OR
 2. delete the file and take back only the file(or only folder) from
    recycle bin.

How is this "belonging to" association created?
Can i do it manually with my code on c# or c++? Or is there any library for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "connected files."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887%28VS.85%29.aspx#connected

It happens automatically if you follow the proper naming convention for creating files and folders.

http://xona.com/2004/07/16.html

It seems to be HTML-specific, so if you are trying to use this feature for anything else, you will probably be out of luck or need to hack together your own version of it.